# EBNF to BNF convert for the expression of <<'while'>> ::= while <'Z'> do begin <'A'> { <'A'> } end

Tags: bnf, ebnf

I'd like to convert EBNF to BNF.

<<'while'>> ::= while <'Z'> do begin <'A'> { <'A'> } end ;

How can I do this?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Comment: <while> ::= while <z> do begin <A> | <while><A> end; ---> I have solved like this. But I'm not sure it is correct or not

Comment: Please edit your question to contain all relevant information